# App close Due to method setSkuID not initialize in com.mapbox.android.telemetry.AppUserTurnstile

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-android, maptiler

I am new to maptiler mapbox development , I download app from maptiler. now I am trying to build that app in to my android studio. but there are some errors. I am following  it's ReadMe file . I put dependency `MapboxGLAndroidSDK.aar` in to lib and also apply mapbox public token and secret token at appropriate place as per ReadMe steps . but still I can't run app due to following error:

```
NoSuchMethodError: No virtual Method setSkuId(Ljava/lang/string;)V in class Lcom/mapbox/android/telemetry/AppUserTurnstile; or its super class
```

these are my mapbox dependencies:

```
com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-core:4.3.0
com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-services:4.3.0
com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-geojson:4.3.0
com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-telemetry:4.3.0
com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-gestures:0.4.0
```

these all are prebuild dependencies now I am working with offline mode so if I have to apply more dependency I have to Downoload jar/aar for it. please suggest me some way to solve these error and successful run .Thanks

Comment: Can you please upload the source code of your project somewhere so that I can look at it? Also - It is not clear from your description which maptiler app you have downloaded - could you post link?

Comment: i download from this `https://www.maptiler.com/mobile/`

Comment: And where did you get source code?

Comment: @spatialguy I purchased from it a year ago and now my paid service is over . I am stuck at this error

Comment: I think you just need correct versions of mapbox libraries which works with mapbox aar library, please contact maptiler at https://support.maptiler.com/add-ticket  and I am sure they will help you out.

Comment: Thanks .. I replaced with all new version of these library. Now I have error that `ClasspathNotfound for com.maobox.turf.TurfMeasurement`.. I  think they split the turf dependency from mapbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I found a way to run my project.
the conclusion is Mapbox updated it all library and split some. So I have to download all (.aar)Libraries from Maven repository and add it to my projects as library dependency to resolve issue regarding Mapbox library.
recently I updated following library with latest version .aar file:

`mapbox-android-sdk`

`mapbox-sdk-services`

`mapbox-sdk-turf`

`mapbox-android-telemetry`

`mapbox-sdk-geojson`

`mapbox-android-core`

`mapbox-android-gestures`

If you have internet connectivity you can directly upgrade all the library.
otherwise you can download from [this link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mapbox.mapboxsdk)